# How to send first pipe result to second one in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins

we use Jenkins as CI tools.
we want to separate login from other process.
we define a job for login, in this job we validate user and if user is valid we get user id.
at other job we need to have user id to generate result,Our problem is how we can send first job result(here:user id) to second one?

Comment: Are you usin unix or windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the use of two plugins:

[EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)
[Parameterize Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

EnvInject allows you to inject variables into the Jenkins environment so they are available even after that build step.

Parameterize Trigger plugin allows you to pass information in this build job to another build job you want to start as parameters.

Once you've determined the username (I assume in some sort of batch or bash, you don't note the OS) you'll need to write it to a file on the system using a `key=value` pair.  Then use EnvInject to get the value from the file into the jenkins environment.  After that you'll use the parameterize trigger plugin to build the next job with parameters.  This will require that you check the `This build is parameterized` box in the second job and that you define the appropriate parameters (perhaps with a default value that you can use to intentionally fail the build if you don't get a good value).

Comment: @thedeveloper That's great, if you found this answer to be the best solution for you can you please mark it as accepted the answer.  On this question it is the only answer, but in general you should upvote any answers that have good content or you find helpful and accept the answer to your question which you find was the best answer for your situtation (and if a better answer comes along later feel free to change the accepted answer to that one instead)